# In Corda, configure the Artemis delivery retry rate, backoff, and timeout?

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis

I'm on a Corda V2 project (but will be migrating to V3 shortly).  Per the [docs](https://docs.corda.net/messaging.html#message-queues)

> Artemis is hidden behind a thin interface...

But I'm exploring some business cases around the queue.  Specifically is any of the following exposed for configuration?  (Couldn't find anything specific in [node config](https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html), but about to look at source.)  Or would I need to do my own broker and specify with `messagingServerAddress`?

- delivery retry rate
- backoff rate
- timeout, or when Artemis gives up on delivering the message

Sorry, might be separate question but can the internal queue be queried to see if a node has proposed tx's still waiting to be sent to a different node?

Comment: I'm coming from an Artemis background and have no experience with Corda.  Can you confirm that you're talking about the Artemis broker itself attempting to deliver messages to clients and not clients attempting to deliver messages to the broker? If that's the case then you can use the "max-delivery-attempts", "redelivery-delay", "redelivery-delay-multiplier", & "max-redelivery-delay" Artemis address-setting elements.

Comment: That's a very good distinction, I had assumed the broker itself was doing delivery but I'll need to dig into Corda for that clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As of Corda 3, these settings are not configurable.

It is recommended not to try and interfere with these settings, as many Corda components do not have timeouts configured.

If your use case *absolutely* requires configuring these settings, please update to original question to explain why :)